# git log variation on standard pretty format output

Tags: git

I would like to get the default standard format, colors and information on this output:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

To extend it with additional information I would like to have.

How can I get the standard format string as a base point?

Answer (score 0):

`git help log`

Look for all the formatting options in the `PRETTY FORMATS` section.

Comment: I know where to find all `PRETTY FORMATS`, thanks.  But I am not asking that.  I would get the format string the command posted uses.  I even figure out what is the format string, but I would like to get it, not figure out it. :-)  I am afraid the only answer to this is look at the GIT code itself.